# print values after each 1000 step

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, ipython

I want to print value after every certain interval (1000) on last line of code than every single value.

```
DARTS=200000
hits = 0
throws = 0
rangen = RanGenerator()
pi = 0
avg = 0
mu = 0
var = 0
dev = 1

for i in range (1, DARTS):
    throws += 1
    x = rangen.rand()
    y = rangen.rand()
    z = rangen.rand()
    tt = x**2 + y**2 + z**2
    dist = sqrt(tt)
    if dist <= 1.0:
        hits = hits + 1.0
        pi = 6 * (hits / throws)
        avg = avg + pi
        mu = avg/throws
        var = (var+(mu-pi)**2)/throws
        dev = sqrt(var)
        print("%d: %s" % (i,dev))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is easy with the modulo operator - it will print the values only when `i` is divisible by `1000`:

```
if i % 1000 == 0:
    print("%d: %s" % (i,dev))
```

Comment: I actually think this was one of those times where a code-only answer actually is appropriate.

Comment: @SethMMorton yeah it's very straightforward